# my react app uses useContext to store login and user info, but if I navigate by changing the URL all info is lost and everything resets

Tags: reactjs, use-context

```
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Profile from "./pages/profile/Profile";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import Messenger from "./pages/messenger/Messenger";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";

function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(user);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {user ? <Home /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/messenger">
          {!user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Messenger />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          {!user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Profile />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          {user ? <Profile /> : "404 ERROR: Page does not exists"}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

That's how my app file looks like. Not sure why navigating the app via URL would cause the app to always reset.

For example, the app does have a widget that when clicked will redirect the user to someone else's profile. But If I navigate to that person's profile using the URL instead, everything resets

Comment: Is your App component wrapped in a context provider which calls `createContext()`? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Comment: yes it is, please see update

Comment: Do you mean you are typing a new address into the address bar or you are clicking on a `<Link/>`? Context is lost on page refresh, but shouldn't with proper router links. I ask, because I don't see any links or `useHistory`s in your code.

Comment: @zero298 I believe that I typing a new address into the address bar. If manipulating the address bar will cause all state to be lost, what is the solution to this then?

Comment: @zero298 and yes, by pressing the refresh page, everything resets.

Comment: Use some context persistence library. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53455443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Context doesn't persist when the URL is navigated to directly.

React Router handles URL changes within the application but by changing the URL directly you're telling the browser to load the page again. Your application will need to handle fetching the data required and re-populating React Context if the pages is landed on directly.

This typically involves confirming that the user is logged it (depending on your authentication method this is usually sorted in a cookie) and then fetching any data required by the page.

There are ways of persisting data between sessions but this should be avoided if possible. [How can we use the same state across multiple tabs(pages) in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384212/how-can-we-use-the-same-state-across-multiple-tabspages-in-react/49385375)